# matlab - optimize getting the angle between each vector with all others in a large array

Tags: matlab, optimization, angle, sparse-matrix

I am trying to get the angle between every vector in a large array (`1896378x4` -EDIT: this means I need `1.7981e+12` angles... TOO LARGE, but if there's room to optimize the code, let me know anyways). It's too slow - I haven't seen it finish yet. Here's the steps towards optimizing I've taken:

First, logically what I (think I) want (just use `Bt=rand(N,4)` for testing):

```
    [ro,col]=size(Bt);
    angbtwn = zeros(ro-1); %too long to compute!! total non-zero = ro*(ro-1)/2
    count=1;
    for ii=1:ro-1
        for jj=ii+1:ro
            angbtwn(count) = atan2(norm(cross(Bt(ii,1:3),Bt(jj,1:3))), dot(Bt(ii,1:3),Bt(jj,1:3))).*180/pi;
            count=count+1;
        end
    end
```

So, I though I'd try and vectorize it, and get rid of the non-built-in functions:

```
[ro,col]=size(Bt);
% angbtwn = zeros(ro-1); %TOO LONG!
for ii=1:ro-1
    allAxes=Bt(ii:ro,1:3);
    repeachAxis = allAxes(ones(ro-ii+1,1),1:3);
    c = [repeachAxis(:,2).*allAxes(:,3)-repeachAxis(:,3).*allAxes(:,2)
        repeachAxis(:,3).*allAxes(:,1)-repeachAxis(:,1).*allAxes(:,3)
        repeachAxis(:,1).*allAxes(:,2)-repeachAxis(:,2).*allAxes(:,1)];
    crossedAxis = reshape(c,size(repeachAxis));
    normedAxis = sqrt(sum(crossedAxis.^2,2));
    dottedAxis = sum(repeachAxis.*allAxes,2);
    angbtwn(1:ro-ii+1,ii) = atan2(normedAxis,dottedAxis)*180/pi;
end
angbtwn(1,:)=[]; %angle btwn vec and itself
%only upper left triangle are values...
```

Still too long, even to pre-allocate... So I try to do sparse, but not implemented right:

```
[ro,col]=size(Bt);
%spalloc:
angbtwn = sparse([],[],[],ro,ro,ro*(ro-1)/2);%zeros(ro-1); %cell(ro,1)
for ii=1:ro-1
    ...same
    angbtwn(1:ro-ii+1,ii) = atan2(normedAxis,dottedAxis)*180/pi; %WARNED: indexing = >overhead
    % WHAT? Can't index sparse?? what's the point of spalloc then?
end
```

So if my logic can be improved, or if sparse is really the way to go, and I just can't implement it right, let me know where to improve. THANKS for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the angle between every *pair* of vectors in `Bt`? If `Bt` has 2 million vectors that's a trillion pairs each (apparently) requiring an inner product to get the angle between. I don't know that any kind of optimization is going to help have this operation finish in a reasonable amount of time in MATLAB on a single machine.

In any case, you can turn this problem into a matrix multiplication between matrices of unit vectors:

```
N=1000;
Bt=rand(N,4); % for testing. A matrix of N (row) vectors of length 4.
[ro,col]=size(Bt);

magnitude = zeros(N,1); % the magnitude of each row vector.
units = zeros(size(Bt)); % the unit vectors

% Compute the unit vectors for the row vectors
for ii=1:ro
  magnitude(ii) = norm(Bt(ii,:));
  units(ii,:) = Bt(ii,:) / magnitude(ii);
end

angbtwn = acos(units * units') * 360 / (2*pi);
```

But you'll run out of memory during the matrix multiplication for largish N.

Comment: Well I'll be honest I never thought how large it would be, I guess I need to think of a new method... But it's a good learning experience in optimization anyways. Also - the vectors Bt(:,1:3) are all unit vectors already - didn't think that was important. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `pdist` with `'cosine'` distance to compute the `1-cos(angbtwn)`.
Another perk for this approach that it does not compute `n^2` values but exaxtly `.5*(n-1)*n` unique values :)